Pixel representations of wallpaper groups
Take a rectangular (including square) patch of square OFF pixels and turn at least one of them ON, then tile the plane with that patch in the obvious way. The symmetries of the tiled plane that map ON pixels to ON pixels will be one of the 12 wallpaper groups without order-3 or -6 rotations. Here are some examples – the repeated patch is marked in red and white:

For each of the aforementioned 12 wallpaper groups – p1, p2, pm, pg, cm, pmm, pmg, pgg, cmm, p4, p4m, p4g – what is the smallest-area patch that generates exactly that group? Ties are broken by fewest ON pixels per patch, then longest short side.
